# Directory Events When New file add C#

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I know if new file was added to specific directory?

I can get an event from directory when new file was added?

I can to make a timer and check each 1000ms if new file was added but i looking for another way?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at the [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class which offers this functionality. The official documentation has many examples on how to subscribe to different events that you are interested in.